# Ignore DTMF while in queue - Asterisk

Tags: asterisk

I required a way to ignore DTMF key-press after outside caller enters a queue.
I'm on Asterisk 1.8LTS

Thanks in advance.

John

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are no way ignore dtmf

But you can use insted of transfer features.conf fetures and can disable features you not need.

Comment: Is there any way to ignore DTMF via, say a "while + endwhile" loop?

Comment: sorry, i not understand what you triing to say. you can read dtmf. or not read it. what is problem?